# How do I store a double (64-bit floating point) or float in the Windows registry?

Tags: .net, windows, floating-point, double, registry

I want to store a `double` (64-bit floating point) into the Window registry.  What's the best way to go about it?

Possible options: both a `long` and a `double` in a 64-bit compiler are 64-bit values so one option is to convert the double to it's 64-bit representation and store it as a registry "qword".  Another option is to store it as a binary stream.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could store it as a base64 encoded string, or whatever. :)

Personally though, I'd store it as a reg_binary rather than converting to and fro, but which ever is easiest really depends on the language.  As far as which one is "more right" I'd say reg_binary.  But the registry is such a dirty hack that I wouldn't feel bad doing something the "wrong" way if it's easier.

Comment: If one cannot be sure that all readers/writers of the data use exactly the same format, one could store as a string (and accept a little rounding in the least significant bits--as there will be in any calculation).

Comment: Looks like VB.NET has BitConverter.DoubleToInt64() and Int64ToDouble(), so I can use that.

Comment: Binary is always the right choice for anything you can't store otherwise, because it enables you to store any value as is without any encoding overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string too.

e.g.

```
var software = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);
var mycompany = software.CreateSubKey("MyCompany");
var emailagent = mycompany.CreateSubKey("EmailAgent");
emailagent.SetValue("SendMailPollingTime", "1000", RegistryValueKind.String);

emailagent = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\MyCompany\\EmailAgent");
double polling = double.Parse((string)emailagent.GetValue("SendMailPollingTime"));
```

Answer (score 0):

one clever trick I saw somewhere was they would store the numerator and denominoator as separate DWORD's, then combine them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all `Windows registry types` in [this page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You should take a look at:

1. REG_SZ - if you use this you can store your double number as a string.
2. REG_QWORD - you can store your double as a double.
3. REG_BINARY - you can store your double as a binary data.

The second probably looks best, however, in such cases I use third option. `flout` and `double` types are based `IEEE754` type, so you can easy explode your number into 64 bits and do not lose any precision (compared with `REG_SZ`).